# "GT0 is not compiled in xil_defaultlib" and "gt is not declared"

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

this is my first time working in VHDL, and I was wondering why I am getting an error of "gt1 is not compiled in library 'xil_defaultlib', and 'gt is not declared' in struc_arch. The purpose of the code is to basically have a 2 bit comparator that will output 1 if a is greater than b.

```
architecture struc_arch of gt2 is
    signal g1 : std_logic;
begin
    gt_bit0_unit : entity work.gt0(sop_arch)
        port map(
            i0 => a(1),
            i1 => b(0),
            gt => g0
        );
    agtb <= gt;
end struc_arch;
```

And the code of the sop_arch that is referenced:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity gt2 is
port (a,b : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
agtb : out std_logic);
end gt2;

architecture sop_arch of gt2 is
begin
agtb <= '1' when (a>b) else
'0';
end sop_arch;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.1 Design unit "... Of the secondary units, only architecture bodies are named; the name of an architecture body is given by the identifier following the reserved word architecture. Each primary unit in a given library shall have a simple name that is unique within the given library, and each architecture body associated with a given entity declaration shall have a simple name that is unique within the set of names of the architecture bodies associated with that entity declaration". The two sop_arch's aren't the same here. Provide a [mcve], complete error message.

Comment: 'gt is not declared' but g1 is declared and unused... "gt0 is not compiled" but there's a gt2 instead. Are these just silly typos?